# keeping viewpager2 item position when navigatiing to other fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager2

I'm using viewpager2 with navigation component. When I click on one item in viewpager, it goes to another fragment, but when I go back to previous fragment with viewpager, the position of viewpager resets to the first one. How can I keep the viewpager position when navigating to other fragment?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish what you want is to have a viewmodel that will save your viewpager position.

**In your fragment:**

```
private lateinit var viewModel : TestViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)

#### all other regular fragment stuff still aplies

}
```

```
fun setViewPager(){

        ### regular VP2 code here (adapter, etc)

viewModel.viewPagerSelected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { page ->
                viewPager.currentItem = page
            })

viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageSelected(page: Int) {
                viewModel.updatePageSelected(page)
            }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class TestViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val _viewPagerSelected = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val viewPagerSelected: LiveData<Int> = _viewPagerSelected

    fun updatePageSelected(newSelection: Int) {
        _viewPagerSelected.postValue(newSelection)
    }

}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: is the **viewPager.currentItem = page** placed after the adapter/data is set?

Comment: After. It works with `viewpager.setCurrentItem(page, false)` but viewpager lags a lot.

Comment: have you tried set the flag to true? This flag refers to "smooth scroll" it shouldnt matter in your case, it should set the item anyways.

Comment: Are you using the latest viewpager2 library?
I have this repo working just fine, take a look 

https://github.com/chenriquevz/PokeDex/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/chenriquevz/pokedex/ui/pokemon/PokemonFragment.kt

https://github.com/chenriquevz/PokeDex/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/chenriquevz/pokedex/ui/pokemon/PokemonViewModel.kt

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `FragmentStateAdapter` with const ItemCount, I guest the position you want to keep is greater than ItemCount.

```
class Adapter(val data: List<String>, fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return  SubFragment.newInstance(data.get(position))
    }
}

viewModel.subFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    Adapter(it,this@fragment)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager2` automatically saved his state, for that you need to set `id`.